# Delete Office365 users from Provider-Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

Could we remotely Delete Office365 users from Provider-Hosted App programatically with C# ?  Any suggestions please.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a question about AD. Although I do not know the exact API, what you are looking for is how to do user maintenance in WAAD. MSoft just released a bunch of new O365 Apis and I am sure WAAD apis were included.

Once you find and test that Api, you should be able to call it from a SP Provider-Hosted app (assuming a credential with appropriate rights.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. You need to provide more detailed answers